# Undefined Method 'metadata' when uploading using mongoid-paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, mongoid

Can't find out why I'm getting this when trying to upload files with Mongoid and Paperclip.

```
undefined method `metadata' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x10625e930>
```

I'm running the following (latest of paperclip, mongoid-paperclip and aws-s3):

```
gem "rails", "3.0.6"
gem "mongoid", "2.0.1"
gem "bson_ext", "1.3.0"
gem "paperclip"
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
gem "aws-s3",            :require => "aws/s3"
```

I've seen places recommending adding the following to an initializer for things that appear to be similar.  I've done this, but to no avail.

```
if defined? ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
    ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.send(:include, Paperclip::Upfile)
end
```

Anyone else encounter this?

Comment: i keep getting this and solving it (but with carrierwave) but i never remember how.  Can you show us your model that is saving the image as well as the form it is being uploaded from.  Pretty please.

Answer (score 1):

I have the the uploader:

```
class Image
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :imageable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
end
```

Which is used in all my classes containing images, such as:

```
class Shop
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :logo, as: :imageable, :class_name => 'Image', cascade_callbacks: true  
end
```

Then in the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @shop do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :cover do |u|%>
    <%= u.file_field :file %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

I think this is a pretty neat way to handle the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<%= f.fields_for :logo do |u|%>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

As I said above, I had a similar problem with Mongoid, **Carrierwave** and GridFS.
My solution is super hacky but it worked for me.
I had an Image class which is where my image was mounted

```
class Image
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title
  field :image
  field :order

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  embedded_in :article
end

class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  embeds_one :image
  ...
end
```

My carrierwave uploader wanted the attributes sent to it with the key of the mount uploader (image).

```
Image.create( :image => image_attributes)
```

But the article's new/edit form created something that looked like:

```
:article => { :image => #ActionDispatch... }
```

instead of

```
:article => { :image => { :image => #ActionDispatch... } }
```

so my solution was to change the name of the field in the form to

```
file_field :article, :photo
```

and then add a photo setter to the article class that created an image

```
model Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  def photo=(attrs)
    create_image(:image => attrs)
  end
end
```

I tried this with image= but it infinitely recursed and did evil things.
I also tried this

```
file_field "article[image]", :image
```

without the setter and it didn't raise an exception but it also didn't save my image.

as far as i know, paperclip is pretty similar in these regards.  Maybe this will work for someone or someone can clean up my mess